# Set delays - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have a simple fire animation. It just show two flames tongues in same place and show hide within 0.3s. Right now I want set delays. After few milliseconds, stop the loop and start again like that. I tried with javascript `setInterval` but it's continuously running.

```js
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
setInterval(function() {
  $wrapper.toggleClass("alt");
}, 300);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.flames,
.wrapper-img,
.show-1,
.show-2 {
  position: absolute;
}

.flames {
  display: none;
}

.flame-1 {
  left: 38px;
  top: 32px;
}

.flame-2 {
  left: 67px;
  top: 40px;
}

.flame-2 img {
  top: 220px;
}

.wrapper-img {
  top: 220px;
}

.wrapper .flame-1 {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .flame-2 {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.alt .flame-1 {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.alt .flame-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flame-1 flames">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0Pfsrdh.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="flame-2 flames">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EypytyC.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper-img">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/moNtPwG.png" class="wrap-img" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any solution? **[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/uy43w5qq/6/)**

Comment: Are you looking for `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`? `setTimeout` only runs once after a delay,  `setInterval` runs continuously until you stop it.

Comment: SetInterval continuously runs, try setTimeout

Comment: you can use css3 instead of that js

Comment: I have answered bellow, but I am not sure that this was your question, could you please explain more detailed your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if i understand correctly, but what you want is this ?

```
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

function startAnimation () {
  var animationCount = 4
  var iterationCount = 0
  var intervalValues = {
    animation: 300,
    loops: 900
  }
  function toggleAlt () {
    $wrapper.toggleClass("alt");
    iterationCount++
    if (iterationCount > 0 && iterationCount % animationCount === 0) {
      setTimeout(toggleAlt, intervalValues.loops)
    } else {
      setTimeout(toggleAlt, intervalValues.animation)
    }
  }
  toggleAlt();
}

startAnimation()
```

i've tried to keep simple, Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50gemkrk/

1. Toggle class few times with interval of few ms.
2. Wait for few ms.
3. Repeat first step: `Toggle class few times with interval of few ms`

---

IMHO,

1. I might be wrong, but `setIntervals` is not recommended in most of cases, it's easy to lose control
2. Also, i agree with [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48459697/6651114), CSS3 Animation is cool, i recomend it !

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see you need soething like this

```
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
function flamebaby(){
    $wrapper.toggleClass("alt");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $wrapper.toggleClass("alt");
      setTimeout(function() {
        flamebaby();
      },600)
  }, 200);

}

flamebaby();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uy43w5qq/7/

Comment: 600 is the delay between animation cycles

Comment: This is so nice! But I need it bit diffrent way. Think 4 times loops run, then a bit delay. Then again start. Like that.

Comment: Just a hint, you could also use a random delay instead of wrapping two `setTimeout` calls with fixed delays. `setInterval(function() { $wrapper.toggleClass("alt"); }, 200 + Math.random() * 400);` That will use a random delay between 200 and 600 (200 + 400) ms. Just wrap it in a function and call it again after the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [CSS keyframe animations](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) which will let you run keyframe based transitions/animations without the need of JavaScript. This will also ensure that the browser can do optimizations for your animations, they will probably run smoother.

JS based answers are already provided so I'm not going in there except for a small sidenote on setInterval.

Using setInterval() is not recommended since the body function theoretically may take longer than the interval causing a stackoverflow. A better way is to use setTimeout to call a function, which at the end of executions schedules a new timeout for itself.

```
const foo = () => {
  console.log('bar');
  setTimeout(foo, 300);
}
setTimeout(foo, 300);
```

Also, when animating is may be useful to first use pen and paper to write down how the animations should behave, this may help when writing the code to implement them.